# translation of excel formula not working in php

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula

i'm having the following excel formula:

```
=-0,00008*A9^2+0,0167*A9+0,465
```

A9 stands for 48 and the (correct) result is 1,08 decimal.

i'm trying to translate this function into php - here's my code:

```
$var = 48;    
$result = -0.00008 * $var^2 + 0.0167 * $var + 0.465;
```

it should be correct but php returns 3 which is wrong.
any ideas what's wrong with my syntax?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [pow](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function to calculate exponential expression.

`^` is bitwise xor operator.

```
$var = 48;    
$result = -0.00008 * pow($var,2) + 0.0167 * $var + 0.465;
```